# Command line arguments Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, nuke

i am working on a software name Foundry Nuke. I am having troubles while passing command line parameters in Mac OSX.

If i use the below command, it works fine and launches the Nuke software.

```
subprocess.Popen(['Application/Nuke6.3v8/Nuke6.3v8.app/Contents/MacOS/Nuke6.3v8'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

But if i add arguments to the command, it doesn't work.
`subprocess.Popen(['Application/Nuke6.3v8/Nuke6.3v8.app/Contents/MacOS/Nuke6.3v8', '-t /.../somepath/init.py', '%s %s' % (someArg1, someArg2)], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

kindly help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 1):

Each individual argument needs to be a separate item in the list.

```
subprocess.Popen(['Application/Nuke6.3v8/Nuke6.3v8.app/Contents/MacOS/Nuke6.3v8',
                  '-t', '/.../somepath/init.py', # not '-t /.../somepath/init.py'
                  someArg1, someArg2,            # not '%s %s'%(someArg1, someArg2)'
                 ], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: You can only use the starred expression as part of the function's argument list, not inside an arbitrary list. You could do use `['Application...', '-t', '/.../somepath/init.py' ] + list(someArglist)`.

Answer (score 0):

To add arguments, add extra items to the list:

```
subprocess.Popen([
    'Application/Nuke6.3v8/Nuke6.3v8.app/Contents/MacOS/Nuke6.3v8',
    '-t', '/.../somepath/init.py',
    some_arg_1, some_arg_2,
], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```